# Overload negation operator for bit field enum

Tags: c++, enums, operator-overloading

I have a class that has a couple members that are bit fields of `enum` type. I wanted to overload the negation operator for the `enum`, because for implementation reasons I can't use the value that's actually zero as the null state. But it looks like the **`operator!` is not getting picked up for the bit fields**, though it seems to work just fine if the values are not bit fields. Is there something special about bit fields that I'm missing?

Here's a test code (with the same number of `enum` values):

```
#include <iostream>

#define TEST(var) std::cout << #var " = " << var << std::endl;

struct flags {
  enum field { f0, f1, no_field };
  field b0 : 4;
  field b1 : 4;
  field a0, a1;
};

inline bool operator!(flags::field f) {
  std::cout << "(!) ";
  return f == flags::no_field;
}

int main() {
  flags f;
  f.b0 = flags::f0;
  f.b1 = flags::f1;
  f.a0 = flags::f0;
  f.a1 = flags::f1;

  std::cout << "******** test enum values" << std::endl;

  TEST( flags::f0 ) // 0
  TEST( flags::f1 ) // 1
  TEST( flags::no_field ) // 2
  TEST( !flags::f0 ) // (!) 0
  TEST( !flags::f1 ) // (!) 0
  TEST( !flags::no_field ) // (!) 1

  std::cout << "\n******** test regular members" << std::endl;

  TEST( f.a0 ) // 0
  TEST( f.a1 ) // 1
  TEST( !f.a0 ) // (!) 0
  TEST( !f.a1 ) // (!) 0

  std::cout << "\n******** test bit field members" << std::endl;

  TEST( f.b0 ) // 0
  TEST( f.b1 ) // 1
  TEST( !f.b0 ) // expected "(!) 0", but got "1"
  TEST( !f.b1 ) // expected "(!) 0", but got "0"
}
```

Here's the output I get [[Wandbox]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WrNztncsu3bFGLHc):

```
******** test enum values
flags::f0 = 0
flags::f1 = 1
flags::no_field = 2
!flags::f0 = (!) 0
!flags::f1 = (!) 0
!flags::no_field = (!) 1

******** test regular members
f.a0 = 0
f.a1 = 1
!f.a0 = (!) 0
!f.a1 = (!) 0

******** test bit field members
f.b0 = 0
f.b1 = 1
!f.b0 = 1
!f.b1 = 0
```

As can be seen from the output of the tests with bit field members, the "(!)" is not printed, and the integral values are negated, rather then compared to the `flags::no_field`.

**Edit**: I've submitted a GCC bug [report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82165).

Comment: @AndyG My point is that `TEST( !f.a )` doesn't print `bool operator!(flags::field)`, so my function is not getting used, and I want to know why.

Comment: I see. Should have read closer.

Comment: I think this is a GCC bug, probably relating to the underlying storage used for the enum or bitfield or both.

Comment: It helps my claim about the GCC bug when both clang and MSVC behave as intended.

Comment: Seems like it is. I tried it with clang [here](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_clang), and it didn't have this problem.